# Which preposition is right in "an answer to/for/of/on + something"?

Tags: prepositions

Which prepositions can come after "an answer" and are natural?

E.g. the below sentence can show the context the phrase would be used.

> I would like to get an answer to/for/of/on this question.

To me, who is not a native English speaker but an intermediate ESL learner, all of them feel natural.

Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more idiomatic usage is ***"an answer to"*** this question. 
The preposition "for" could be used alternatively but it is less common.

Other preposition can be used but are much less common as shown in [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=an%20answer%20to%2C%20an%20answer%20for%2C%20an%20answer%20on%2C%20an%20answer%20of%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Can%20answer%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Can%20answer%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Can%20answer%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Can%20answer%20of%3B%2Cc0) and they may convey different meanings.

Comment: Thank you for answering, Absolute Beginner. Can I ask you a little bit more of examples or explanations about what differences could be made when prepositions other than "to" or "for" are used?

Comment: @SmartHumanism - you can see usage examples inside the Ngram link (just click on dates below).  If you have doubts  you can ask.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I am greeting as I review this post in a long time. :) Happy New Year to you.